# Let client create user but not modify untill authenticated

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

im writting an app using backbone.js in roder to learn. you can find what I actually got here: https://the-todo-app.firebaseapp.com/

My idea is to allow people register in the app using simpleLogin with facebook to create user, then they are redirected to their users and are allowed to create and modify their todos, but the problem i have is that actually every user has the posibility to write on the users folder, which means they can enter and delete or modify data from other users. I would like to restrict the security from firebase to allow them create their user based on their id but doesnt allow them to write if they are not authenticated. This is what i actually have:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "data.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])",
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id"
      }          
    }
  }
}
```

Aso tried this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id"
      }          
    }
  }
}
```

but this approach doesnt allow the client to create an user id.

This is how my data actually looks:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "10152111176005069" : {
      "name" : "Jhonnatan Gonzalez Rodriguez",
      "picture" : "url to pic"
    },
    "10154397958535078" : {
      "name" : "Diana Rincón P",
      "picture" : "url to pic"
    },
    "10152167159946759" : {
      "name" : "Sebastian Ayala",
      "picture" : "url to pic"
    }
  },
  "title" : "The todo app"
}
```

I will appreciate if you guys have an idea of how to do this.

Based on ArneHugo's answer i just setted up this rules and seems to work pretty well, I will need to do more testing in order to be sure.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".write": "!data.child(auth.id).exists()",
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
      }          
    }
  }  
}
```

I actually had to add the users the .read rule to true in order to allow them to check if data exist, this is how rules looks now.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "!data.child(auth.id).exists()",
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
      }          
    }
  }  
}
```

And this is how the outputs looks for an anonymous user

```
Attempt to write {"id":"6726363"} to /users/6726363 with auth=null
    /
    /users:.write: "!data.child(auth.id).exists()"
5:30: child() expects a string argument.
        => false
    /users/6726363:.write: "$user == auth.id"
        => false
    /users/6726363:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => false

Validation failed.
Write was denied.
```

And this is how looks for an authenticated user.

```
Attempt to write {"name":"6726363","picture":"fb picture"} to /users/6726363 with auth={"id":"6726363"}
    /
    /users:.write: "!data.child(auth.id).exists()"
        => true
    /users/6726363:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => true
    /users/6726363:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => true

Write was allowed.
```

And this is the uoutput for an anonymous trying to write in another user data.

```
Attempt to write {"name":"6726363","picture":"fb picture"} to /users/10152111176005069 with auth=null
    /
    /users:.write: "!data.child(auth.id).exists()"
5:30: child() expects a string argument.
        => false
    /users/10152111176005069:.write: "$user == auth.id"
        => false
    /users/10152111176005069:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => true

No .write rule allowed the operation.
Write was denied.
```

Now, making this examples found that an authenticated user with an existed id in database can writte another's user data like this.

```
Attempt to write {"name":"6726363","picture":"fb picture"} to /users/10152111176005069 with auth={"id":"6726363"}
    /
    /users:.write: "!data.child(auth.id).exists()"
        => true
    /users/10152111176005069:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => true
    /users/10152111176005069:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
        => true

Write was allowed.
```

Comment: Have you looked an [anonymous auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-anonymous.html)? That may be a better solution than an insecure and possibly hacky write rule.

Comment: @Kato I think the problem is if I set an anonymous auth the user will have writte acces in a top level wich means every authenticated user is in the cappability to create as many users as he wants in the users/ path, becasue is already authenticated.... I am having big problems with the fact I can not have nested security rules for that

Comment: Security rules cascade. If you allow write at root, then the user can write at any level under root. If you want to restrict them to their own path, remove the rule at root.

Comment: @Kato but if I remove the wrtie on the top level if the user is not register it is not going to be able to create its uder on the db :/

Comment: Write permissions at the root level allow any user to edit any data without logging in. Use a different solution. It's typical for users to need to create an auth token using createUser() and login() before writing their new profile.

Comment: Question, do you want unauthenticated users to be able to read or write? Or do you agree that that part is now working correctly (e.g. they have now access)? Cause I don't see a reason to allow unauthenticated users any access whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is entirely possible, and I don't agree with Kato that you should use a different kind of login.

This is all you need:

```
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      //".write": "!data.exists()", /* Edit: removed, as it always returned false */
      "$user": {
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture'])"
      }          
    }
  }
```

1. New users can add an $user entry for themselves.
2. No user can read from a $user other than their own.
3. No user can write to a $user other than their own (including when they create it in the first place, which ensures valid entries).
4. $user entries must have name and picture. (Note that I moved your validate rule.)

Protip: Use the simulator in Firebase to test the security rules. It's a great and simple tool.

**Edit**

*I did a test to see if you really do need a read rule to check if data exists. (Answer: you don't.)*

With the following security rules

```
"test": {
    ".write": "!data.child(auth.id).exists()",
    "$user": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture']) && $user == auth.id",
        ".read": "$user == auth.id",
        ".write": "$user == auth.id"
    }          
}
```

Tried to write a new user:

```
Attempt to write {"name":"Beardinator","picture":"i.imgur.com/axXz9sr.jpg"} to /test/1337 with auth={"id":"1337"}
    /:.write: "root.child('adminPanel').child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() != null"
20:67: child() expects a string argument.
        => false
    /test:.write: "!data.child(auth.id).exists()"
        => true
    /test/1337:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture']) && $user == auth.id"
        => true
    /test/1337:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'picture']) && $user == auth.id"
        => true

Write was allowed.
```

In my test I can check whether data exists just fine without a .read rule on "users".

Comment: Hello,I actually tested in the simulator  but the ".write": "!data.exists()" rule doesn't allow me to create a new user even if the user is authenticated

Comment: I edited the question to show you how actually a setted up the rules based in your answers, seems to work well that way.

Comment: The "!data.exists()" returns false every time, so I removed it. But writing still works for me the way it should. 
Can you show the output you get in the simulator when trying to write a new user?

Comment: Hey, I added the detials you ask for. I actually found one error with the approach :(

Comment: Hey, please remove the .write rule inside "users". The other write rule, the one inside "$user" is sufficient to allow exactly what you want but nothing more. (Also the write rule you have right now is  wrong, it allows a user to change _any_ user as long as she herself is not added to the database yet. That's not what you want. But as I said just remove the .write rule and it should work just right.)

Comment: Also please remove the .read rule inside "users", unless you want users to be able to be able to read all the data on all the users.

Comment: I noticed that if i remove the read rule, firebase can not verify if datta exists or not, thats why i added it. I would like to give you the bounty for all the help provided i appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you :) First of all, you do not need to check if data exists (I removed the .write rule that uses data.exists()). Secondly, even if you do need it, you don't need the read rule on users (see my edited answer). Please copy the rules I use (the 1st ones in my answer), and if you still don't get it to work paste another output from the simulator. It really should work, and it works for me :)